# ObjC Lbrary Usage: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have XCode library I wrote which I use inside Unity3D application.
The library works and now I need to make a change in the implementation, not the interface.
The problem is that in the XCode project created from Unity3D, when I use my library .a file I get this error (I've remove the specific class names).

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ABNUnityativeController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ABUnityNativeController in libABSDK_Unity_NativeController_iOS.a(ABUnityNativeController.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_ABNativeController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ABUnityNativeController in libABSDK_Unity_NativeController_iOS.a(ABUnityNativeController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is how I compile my library.

Answer (score 0):

I find that my project settings were bad.
When I choose the main project (I also have sub XCode project in it) inside Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries I had to add my sub-project which was listed under Workspace directory.